# Overridden edits show wrong action label ("SuggestedEditOverrideToRejected") on network profile activity page

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, profile-page, network-profile, edit-override

The network profile activity page shows a wrong label for when a post owner/moderator overrides a suggested edit:

[image: "SuggestedEditOverrideToRejected" as suggested edit action (wrong) on network profile]

The proper label is found on the per-site profile:

[image: "Reject" as proper suggested edit action on per-site all activity page]